# monacaでのCordovaのエラー

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaでアプリを作成しているのですが、毎回アプリを起動するとCordovaのエラーが発生します。
直し方がわからず困っている状態です。
以下のエラーログを記入します。

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
```

このエラーが発生することでアプリにはどのうような影響を及ぼすのでしょうか？
また、エラーを直すためにはどのうようなことをすればいいのですか？

Answer (score 1):

このエラーは、cordovaの起動時の動作が正しく実行されていないときに起こります。
これが発生すると、cordovaのすべての機能が使えなくなってしまいます。

まずは、読み込んでいるjavascriptコードをコメントアウトしたり、プラグインをoffにしたりして、devicereadyイベントが正しく起動される状態にしましょう。

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { alert("DeviceReady"); } , false );
```

のようなコードを記述しておき、アプリ起動時にDeviceReadyと表示されれば成功です。(プレビューではDeviceReadyイベントは発火しないので注意）

devicereadyイベントが発火するようになったら、コメントしてある範囲を徐々に狭めて、どこが原因でdevicereadyが発火していないかを調べてみてください。